# django-form-designer admin URLs not going through

Tags: django, plugins, django-cms

I'm setting up a website using django-cms and wanted to use [philomat's django-form-designer](https://github.com/philomat/django-form-designer) I downloaded it and followed the steps as laid out in the readme, but when I go to the admin, I can see there's a category for the app, but none of the two links go through...they give 404's.

What could I be missing?  The app is exactly what I want and would be glad if someone has insight on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I managed to solve the issue....the instructions say you can skip adding `form_designer` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, but adding it solved my problem.  Hope this helps someone in future